# Print view Android webview pre version 4.4

Tags: android, css, view, printing, webview

Is there any way to get print friendly view from WebView (HTML with CSS) prior to KitKat?

Print mediatype is defined in the CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My research shows that the only way to get print friendly view from a WebView is to create a bitmap from the View.